# Does Absolute Value Preserve Inequality?

Tags: analysis

More Specifically,

If $x-y \leq z$, then is $|x-y| \leq |z|$?

Answer (score 1):

No:

If $x-y = -4\,$ and $\,z = -2,\;$ then $\;|x-y|=4\,$ and $\,|z| = 2$.

Comment: What if x, y, and z are all strictly positive?
edit: nevermind, using z=2 in your example is still a failure of the inequality.

Comment: Take $x = 0, y = 2$ and $z=1$. Then $x-y=-2 \leq 1 = z$, but $|x-y| = 2 > 1 = |z|$.